# Get array of dates from an array of dates

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I have an array of `Date` objects like the following example:

```
let dates = [date1, date2, date3, date4, date5]
```

How can I create subarrays for dates that have the same `day of month`, `month` and `year`.

Example:

```
date1 = 20/04/2020
date2 = 19/04/2020
date3 = 19/04/2020
date4 = 18/04/2020
date5 = 18/04/2020
...
```

With this I wanted the following:

```
let group1 = [date1]
let group2 = [date2, date3] 
let group3 = [date4, date5]
let group4 = //...
```

I have tried `DateComponents` and `.map`, `.filter`, etc functions but somehow I cannot do this.

Can I get a hint?

thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group array of dates by months in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57282990/how-to-group-array-of-dates-by-months-in-swift)

Comment: I'll have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code extracts the date components for year, month and day from each date and groups by them and then maps the values from the grouped result to an array of arrays per date. To be able to have the original dates in the end result a tuple is used as value type for the dictionary

```
let groupedDates = Dictionary(grouping: dates
    .map { ($0,Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: $0))}, by: {$0.1})
    .mapValues {value in value.map {$0.0}}
    .values
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create structure that tracks the year, month, and day.

```
struct DateCluster {
    let day: Int
    let month: Int
    let year: Int

    var dates: [Date] = []

    init(date: Date) {
        let cal = Calendar.current
        day = cal.component(.day, from: date)
        month = cal.component(.month, from: date)
        year = cal.component(.year, from: date)

        dates.append(date)
    }

    func doesDateBelong(_ date: Date) -> Bool {
        let cal = Calendar.current
        return cal.component(.day, from: date) == day
            && cal.component(.month, from: date) == month
            && cal.component(.year, from: date) == year
    }
}
```

And here's the usage:

```
func makeDate(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) -> Date? {
    let cal = Calendar.current
    let components = DateComponents(year: year, month: month, day: day)
    return cal.date(from: components)
}

var clusters: [DateCluster] = []


var dates = [
    makeDate(year: 2020, month: 4, day: 20),
    makeDate(year: 2020, month: 4, day: 19),
    makeDate(year: 2020, month: 4, day: 19),
    makeDate(year: 2020, month: 4, day: 18),
    makeDate(year: 2020, month: 4, day: 18),
].compactMap { $0 }


for date in dates {
    if let index = clusters.firstIndex(where: { $0.doesDateBelong(date) }) {
        clusters[index].dates.append(date)
    } else {
        clusters.append(.init(date: date))
    }
}
```

The result below will be an array of an array of dates all grouped by year, month, and day.

```
let groupedDates = clusters.map { $0.dates }
```

Comment: This answer seems that will indeed solve my issue.
I'll try this out then I'll feedback ;)