# Sort a dictionary by month

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a dictionary that is as follows:

```
var dict: [Date:Int]
```

In my app, I would like to 'sort' the values based on the month. So for example, if my dictionary looks like this:

```
dict = [01-01-2020: 10, 01-15-2020: 17, 01-16-2020: 6, 02-03-2020: 8, 02-04-2020: 10]
```

I would like to be able to convert it to a dictionary that looks like this:

```
dict = [01-01-2020: [10,17,6], 02-01-2020: [8,10]]
```

What is the best way to tackle this problem?

Comment: As the answer says, Dictionary isn't sortable so this cannot be done. Question: What is it that you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @gnasher729 Yeah I know you cannot sort a dictionary, but I would like to ultimately convert from [Date: Int] to [Date: [Int]] with each month being a different dictionary key

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary` is not sortable! Also it seems like you are trying to group your dictionary's data by date. So:

1. First:
   Group dictionary values.
2. Then:
   Convert it to an array.
3. Then:
   Sort the array.

**Note that** steps 2 & 3 can be used together by calling `sorted` directly on the groupedDictionary.

Something like:

```
let sortedGroupedDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: dict) { getMonth(of: $0.key) } .sorted { $0.key < $1.key }
```

You should be able to get month of the date following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57282990).

Comment: Really,? I think we can use  sorted method on dictionaries and choose to sort by either keys or values. something like  ```dictionary.sorted{$0.key  < $1.key}```

Comment: You are right @MussaCharles. Step 2 and 3 can be merged.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which does somewhat similar to what you want. I have used your sample data with few modifications on making sure keys are date objects.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyy"
let dict:[Date:Int] = [dateFormatter.date(from: "01-01-2020")!: 10, dateFormatter.date(from: "01-15-2020")!: 17, dateFormatter.date(from: "01-16-2020")!: 6, dateFormatter.date(from: "02-03-2020")!: 8, dateFormatter.date(from: "02-04-2020")!: 10]
let groupedDict = (Dictionary(grouping: dict, by: {Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day,.month,.year], from: $0.key).month!}).sorted(by: {$0.key < $1.key}))

for (month,groupedDate) in groupedDict {
    print("\(month) : \(groupedDate.map{$0.value})")
}
```

Output: -

```
1 : [6, 10, 17]
2 : [8, 10]
```

Comment: this would group it by months regardless of their years

Comment: Isn’t that what your question say?

Comment: this is not my question but it doesn't make any sense to group this month elements with another year's month elements

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the startOfMonth from each date and group them:

```
extension Calendar {
    static let iso8601 = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
}
```

---

```
extension Date {
    var startOfMonth: Date {
        Calendar.iso8601.date(from: Calendar.iso8601.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: self))!
    }
}
```

---

```
let grouped = dict.reduce(into: [:]) { 
    $0[$1.key.startOfMonth, default: []].append($1.value)
}
```

---

This would result in:

```
2020-01-01 [10, 17, 6]
2020-02-01 [10, 8]
```

Note that a dictionary is an unordered collection so the resulting order of the integers array is unpredictable .

---

---

Another option is to use the Dictionary grouping initializer

```
init<S>(grouping values: S, by keyForValue: (S.Element) throws -> Key) rethrows where Value == [S.Element], S : Sequence
```

to group your dictionary by the `startOfMonth` of its `key` and then map their values using the `Dictionary` method `mapValues`:

```
let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: dict) { $0.key.startOfMonth }
    .mapValues { $0.map(\.value) }
```