# How to group with month & year object with date array

Tags: ios, swift

I am parsing Json as

```
{
  "dataObject": [
    {
      "dateEpoch": 1627516800000,
      "serialNo": 1
    },
    {
      "dateEpoch": 1604880000000,
      "serialNo": 2
    }
  ]
}

 struct PurpleData: Codable {
    var dataObject: [DataObject]?
    struct DataObject: Codable {
        var dateEpoch, serialNo: Int?
    }
}
```

***I am looking for Json/Model to be Grouped by months as----->***

```
{
  "dataObject": [
    {
      "date": "Jan 2020",// MM YYYY date
      "subobject": [
        {
          "serialNo": 1
        },
        {
          "serialNo": 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "date": "Feb 2020",
      "subobject": [
        {
          "serialNo": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So the `JSON` will be sort as **MM YYYY** based. i Dont know how to achive it.
So looking to achive final codable model with updated JSON.
I tried with Array of key pair but could not succeed.

Comment: "I am looking for Json to be sort as----->" Why? What's your use? If it's to show it into a `UITableView` in your app, you don't want JSON, you want a model. It's up to you top transform if needed your received data into your target model. If that's a case, use an intermediary level, or a lazy var to do so, since the parsing is already working...

Comment: @Larme Yes i want to show it on `UItableView` based on `MM YYYY` wise so it will be grouped by months

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57282990/how-to-group-array-of-dates-by-months-in-swift etc, plenty on how to group dates by month. Then a little modification to handle you additional needs. Also, it would be better if you parse `dateEpoch` directly as a `Date`, not a `Int`.

Comment: @Amit grouping by `MM YYYY` will group months of different years as well. What you probably want is to group by year and month `YYYYMM`

Comment: @LeoDabus i am looking to convert my model with grouping months as - `Dec 2020, Jan 2021 etc....`

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment. Your grouping method will make any month even if it is on year 2000 to come before another month of this year. As it is it will group Dec 00, Dec 01, Dec 02, Jan 00, Jan 01, Jan 02, ...

Comment: @LeoDabus understood :) hence sorting also required or `YYYYMM`

Comment: @Amit just make sure to sort your model using the date components not the month names

Comment: @LeoDabus any example code snippet please ?